# Fancybox with content absolute position

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

I have implemented fancybox this way:

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="href">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="mysrc">
</a>
<div class="texthover">
   some text
</div>
```

I gave a position absolute to the texthover div cause I want it to be perfectly over the image, and to give it an effect on mouse over. But with that position absolute fancybox stops working, it does just nothing. If I remove position absolute from that div it works again. Any idea why?

thanks a lot

Comment: What do you mean with "stops working"?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.texthover').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.fancybox').css('z-index', 101);
});

$('.texthover').mouseleave(function(){
    $('.fancybox').css('z-index', -1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

ok found the answer myself after a while. that div was fully covering the link, so I just wrapped the link over both elements.